# Allocating a property

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

Working on someone else's code. Came across a piece of code while analyzing the project

```
self.groupPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,260,320,216)];
self.groupPicker.delegate = self;
self.groupPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.groupPicker];
```

Where groupPicker is a `UIPicker` property. When analyzing the project I encountered a potential leak warning in this case. I have also noticed that the groupPicker property is not being released in the `dealloc` method. Nor is `_groupPicker` released anywhere in the project. What should be done in this case?

1. Should I remove the `UIPicker` property and just declare a `UIPicker` variable instead.
2. Should I just release groupPicker like `[_groupPicker release];`

What would be the retain count of groupPicker as it is retained once in the .h file and again being allocated as shown in the above piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, it is perfectly fine to have the property, the problem is that it is being over retained. When you alloc/init the retain count is 1, then you use the retained property which increases the retain count again. The retain count is now 2 and assuming you release the object in dealloc, you end up with a retain count of 1, i.e. a leaked object.

There are many ways you can handle the problem. I think the best way is to autorelease the object on initialization. Like so

```
self.groupPicker = [[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,260,320,216)] autorelease];
```

2) Anything you retain should be released in dealloc, so in dealloc you should

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_groupPicker release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)

to do so got to edit>refactor>convert to objective c ARC

Comment: Active Resource Counting? Where did you get that? It's Automatic Reference Counting.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out! When you set a property like

```
self.property1 = x;
```

and the property1 is declared as retain, the previous object in the property1 is released and the new object (x) is retained. This is why doing this:

```
self.property1 = [[x alloc] init];
```

when property1 is declared as retain, will retain x twice. (one for init, one for setting the property)
The correct way is declaring the object, setting to the property and then releasing

```
object x = [[class alloc] init];
self.property1 = x;
[x release];
```

This way, you give the "responsability" of releasing the object x to the property holder.

Answer (score 0):

While using **ARC** for iOS5+ applications should be preferred, if you don't want to do that just use `autorelease` after `init` method.

Answer (score -1):

Either assign the UIPickerView to `_groupPicker` (or whatever the instance variable is named), or use an `autorelease` on the value as you assign it.

(The problem is that assigning to a retained property causes a retain, and there's already a retain on the object from the `alloc`.)